# Javascript - Restructure array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js, formatting

I currently have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "key":"CES0000000001",
        "25568.95655":"29923",
        "25568.96078":"31603"
    },
    {
        "key":"CES0000000001",
        "25568.96501":"34480",
        "25568.96924":"38347"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to restructure this data to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "key":"CES0000000002",
        "values": [ [ 25568.95655 , 29923 ] , [ 25568.96078 , 31603 ] ]
    },

    {
        "key":"CES0000000002",
        "values": [ [ 25568.96501 , 34480 ] , [ 25568.96924 , 38347 ] ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone provide some advice for this and any good resources for restructuring javascript objects?  I'm getting more into visualization using d3.js and data formatting is key.

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is loop over the array and create some now objects with a `key` and `values` property. What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: And where is the second object getting its `key` from? It's not represented in the original data.

Comment: Corrected the typo with the second object key. I'm just not accustomed to working with arrays/objects and wasn't sure which methods I should be using here. iSchluff provided a straightforward example that gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

my solution would be

```
    var arr= [
    {
        "key":"CES0000000001",
        "25568.95655":"29923",
        "25568.96078":"31603"
    },
    {
        "25568.96501":"34480",
        "25568.96924":"38347"
    }
];

var transformed= arr.map(function(obj){
    var result= {
        key: obj.key,
        values: []
    }

    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== "key") {
          result.values.push([key, obj[key]]);
      }
    }
    return result;
});

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post I see, but I want to share how you could do this with es6 object destructuring and restructuring.
if you have an object...

```
const obj1 = {
    "key":"CES0000000001",
    "25568.95655":"29923",
    "25568.96078":"31603"
};
```

you could have:

```
const restructure = ({key, ...values}) => ({key, Object.entries(values)});
const obj2 = restructure(obj1);
```

or for the array you could restructure all of them with:

```
const b = arr.map(({key, ...values}) => ({key, Object.entries(values)}));
```

or if you are reusing the function...

```
const b = arr.map(restructure);
```